# numpy builds on docker buildx exceeds build times way more than an hour

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, buildx

### System

- `Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d`
- Windows 10 Pro with Docker Desktop

As a requirement I have to port my Python3.x application to support working on `arm/v7` architecture hardware. I have GitHub Workflows that can build for `linux/arm64` and `linux/amd64` platforms/architectures. One of the dependency is `numpy` which, during build phase causes build times to exceed more than 30 mins.

Its wheel creation phase does not seem to be moving. In order to avoid complexity in my builds I avoid using `alpine` based images but stick to `slim` images and install the necessary packages in a multi-stage docker build

Dockerfile looks the following:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim AS compile-image

# This prevents Python from writing out pyc files
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# This keeps Python from buffering stdin/stdout
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc

RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY setup.py .
COPY . .
RUN pip install .

FROM python:3.7-slim AS build-image
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/venv /opt/venv
COPY scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
# Make sure we use the virtualenv:
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD ["app", "-c", "config.yaml"]
```

### Outputs

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/arm/v/7 -t myDockerAcc/pyapp .
```

```sh
[+] Building 162.2s (8/17)
[+] Building 1554.2s (10/17)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.67kB                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                           0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim                                                                                                                                          2.2s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [build-image 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim@sha256:c2cc09c3de140f59b3065b9518fa7beb5fbedb4414762963bfe01079ce219f2e                                                                 0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim@sha256:c2cc09c3de140f59b3065b9518fa7beb5fbedb4414762963bfe01079ce219f2e                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                           0.7s
 => => transferring context: 4.77kB                                                                                                                                                                         0.7s
 => [compile-image 2/9] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                                 31.8s
 => [compile-image 3/9] RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential gcc                                                                                                                102.7s
 => [compile-image 4/9] RUN python -m venv /opt/venv                                                                                                                                                       55.8s
 => [compile-image 5/9] COPY requirements.txt .                                                                                                                                                             0.3s
 => [compile-image 6/9] RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt                                                                                                                               1361.0s
 => => #   Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): started
 => => #   Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
 => => #   Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517): still running...
```

Are there certain optimizations one needs to setup / configure during such cross-platform builds so that build times for wheel creations of `numpy` `scipy` or `pandas` would be reduced?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Difference is `opencv` was taking too much time for building and was getting the same output `Building wheel for opencv (PEP 517): still running...`

Changing the python image version in Dockerfile solved my problem.
Try once with `python:3.7-buster` it will not take that long for building numpy.

Comment: but do you also use the final image to be shipped as a `buster` base image or only to build the opencv requirements?

Comment: to ship as well. I understand it is heavier than slim but not that heavy, it will still be light weight. Apart from that you can try another flavours as well if changing the version works for you.